# How can the sum of two closed cones be not closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Can there be two closed cones $K_1$ and $K_2$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ such that $K_1+K_2$ need not be closed?

Comment: see [these notes](http://www.hss.caltech.edu/~kcb/Notes/AsymptoticCones.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this can happen. Let $K_1 = \{(x,y,z) : x^2+y^2\leq z^2 \}$ be the second order cone in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $K_2 = \{ t(1,0,-1) : t \geq 0\}$.

Then $(0,1,0)$ is not an element of $K_1 + K_2$. But
$(0,1,0) = \lim_{t \to \infty} [t(1,0,-1) + (-t,1+1/t,\sqrt{t^2+(1+1/t)^2})]$.